# Swift: Get the correct file size for JPEG image

Tags: swift

I have a `UIImage` object, say from the camera roll via `PHAsset`. The image is saved as a `.jpg` file:

```
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil) { (input, nil) in
    print(input?.fullSizeImageURL) // somefile.jpg
}
```

To get the file size should not `data.count` from this return the correct file size in bytes?

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { data, _, _, _ in
      if let _data = data {
          print(_data.count) // 6759240
      }
}
```

The output for a particular image is `6759240` while `fileSize()` returns `2978548.0` (which is the right file size) bytes.

```
func fileSize(forURL url: Any) -> Double {
    var fileURL: URL?
    var fileSize: Double = 0.0
    if (url is URL) || (url is String)
    {
        if (url is URL) {
            fileURL = url as? URL
        }
        else {
            fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: url as! String)
        }
        var fileSizeValue = 0.0
        try? fileSizeValue = (fileURL?.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.fileSizeKey]).allValues.first?.value as! Double?)!
        if fileSizeValue > 0.0 {
            fileSize = (Double(fileSizeValue))
        }
    }
    return fileSize
}
```

Does it mean `someUIImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.count` does not return the correct size of `JPEG` image file (if saved)?

One more thing, Is there any way to determine the image file size before writing it on the disk?

*All of these is to compare the file size between the original and compressed image.*

Comment: what is actual image size? I mean width * height?

Comment: File size not image dimension.

Comment: this 6759240 you get from someUIImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.count?

Comment: Correct, but the actual file size is what I get from `fileSize` function. I have tried it with several images and in all case `. jpegData(:).count ` returns a weird size.

Comment: I'm asking what is the size of that someUIImage, width * height returns you 6759240 or 2978548.0

Comment: Oh are you talking about dimension? that's not what i'm talking about! The image is 3024x4032 by the way.

Comment: Your jpeg image is compressed but UIImage always uses uncompressed data internally.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How can it uncompress an image file?! the file is already compressed on disk.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, maybe because I wrote uncompress when I mean decompress. The `data` variable in the completion handler contains decompressed image data

Comment: I thought the question is clear. What I'm doing is picking an image from the gallery and calculate the jpeg representation size which I assumed would be the file size if it was written to the disk. But now when I read an image from galley and count the size, it's different than actual file size.

Comment: The data you get when calling requestImageData is not the exact data in the file but the UIImage representation of that data and the way UIImage stores the data internally makes it larger.

Comment: when use `PHImageManager.default().requestImageData` this get original image from disk , but `jpegData ` get compression image not get real size

Comment: Can you print your input mediaType?

Comment: that's `.image` of course!

Comment: "One more thing, Is there any way to determine the image file size before writing it on the disk?" No need to write it to disk, data.count returns the number of bytes you need to write it to disk

Comment: @LeoDabus That's my question! data.count shows, for example 230812 but the saved file is 318 KB.

Comment: Your image it is probably HEIC

Comment: No it is not. In the question I have stated it is a JPEG image.

Comment: I mean the imageData. What makes you so sure about it?

Comment: For the last part of the question, how come `UIImage.jpegData` produces HEIC image?!

Comment: I never said that. I said that the imageData is probably  HEIC. jpegData obviously will return the image data compressed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196991/discussion-between-maysam-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a misunderstanding of what the various terms and calls refer to.

You have no direct access to a file stored in the user's Photo library. There may in fact be no such file; you should make no assumptions about the storage format. When you ask PHImageManager for an image's `data`, you are given the bitmap data, ready for use. Thus you should expect this data to be *big*, in exact proportion to the dimensions of the image. 6759240 is more than 6MB, which sounds about right on an older iPhone; a newer iPhone, takes 4032x3024 photos which is more than 8MB.

Then in a different part of your code you call `fileSize(forURL:)`. Now you're looking at an actual file, in the file system, in a place where you can access it. If this is an image file, it is compressed; just how much it is compressed depends on the format. 2978548 is about 3MB which is pretty good for a JPEG compressed without too much lossiness.

Finally, you ask about UIImage `jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.count`. You do not show any code that actually calls that. But this is data ready for saving as a file directly with `write(to:)` and a URL, and I would expect it to be the same as `fileSize(forURL:)` if you were to check the very same file later.

Comment: For the first part, you are right, PHImageManager does not access to the actual file, to get that I need to use PHAssetManager. But for the last question, the sizes are different, the written file is larger, about ~25%, than the data.count number. I have to mention that to write the file in the gallery i'm using PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges()

Comment: Well I can't reproduce that ("for the last question"). When I extract a UIImage's `jpegData` and look at its `count`, I get exactly the same result as I get when I write it to disk and then call your `fileSize`. — Note that with `PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges() ` we are _not_ writing the file to disk in the way I describe; we are back to the _first_ paragraph of my answer, talking about the stuff in the photo library and what you get when you ask for the data (you get _uncompressed bitmap_ data).